# Django: How to construct query that includes related latest?

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model that is doing something like this:

```
class Job(Model):
    ...

class Attempt(Model):
    job = ForeignKey(Job)
    attempt_number = PositiveIntegerField()

class StatusHistory(Model):
    attempt = ForeignKey(Attempt)
    state = CharField()
```

As the job goes through various states, a state is added to the history.  As it goes through various attempts, an attempt is added.

Often I find myself wanting to construct a query that iterates over all of the jobs where the current (i.e., latest) attempt is in a particular (current, latest) state.

I know I can say job.attempt_set.latest() to get the latest attempt for *a particular* job, but being able to query for, say,

```
Job.objects.filter(attempt_set__latest__state_set__latest__state='final')
```

Just doesn't seem possible.

I am inclined to add another foreign key to Job or Attempt for the latest attempt/state and just keep it up to date in a transaction when I add an attempt/state history.

Thoughts?  Is this a well known design pattern?  What would you do?

Comment: This may be similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16502903/django-filter-by-latest-related-object

Comment: I think I am just leaning towards adding a current_state and current_attempt and just make sure it is always up to date.  It is kind of redundant, but seems to make a lot of things simpler -- it reduces the complexity to a single function that adds an attempt/state to also update the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, you just have to fallback to the good-and-old SQL using `extra()`. How would you resolve it?

```
Job.objects.extra(
    select={'lastest_state': '''(select state from app_statushistory T1
    join app_attempt T2 on T1.attempt_id=T1.id
    where T2.job_id=app_job.id
    order by id desc limit 1)'''},
    where=['lastest_state=%s'],
    params=['final'])
```

Replace any `app_<tablename>` ocurrences with the actual table names (and `order by id` with another sort if you have it).

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) are the docs for `extra()`.

Comment: Thank you -- but I would like to stick strictly within the ORM.